# cambiar puerto por defecto de spring tools studio

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite, spring-data

estoy realizando mi primer microservicio y deseo pasarlo a producción, pero antes requiero cambiarle el puerto que esta por defecto en el proyecto, ejemplo :8088

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he actualizado el proyecto varias veces pero sigue ejecutando al puerto por defecto que tiene su tomcat embebido "8080" ...De ante mano les agradezco cualquier sugerencia.. El IDE que estoy usando es la ultima versión de Spring Tools Studio

Comment: Probaste con hacer mvn clean install ??

Comment: Sip, pero sigue ejecutándose hacia el puerto 8080 .__. .... ando todo el día revisando foros pero no cambia el puerto... .-.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es la indentación de la propiedad `server` en el archivo `application.yml`, cuando se utiliza un archivo `.yml` ya sea para spring o cualquier otro programa, la indentación de las propiedades es muy importante para que el interprete lea correctamente la propiedad.

La propiedad correcta es `server.port=8088` pero según tu imagen tienes `spring.port=8088` porque `port y server` están al mismo nivel de `datasource y jpa`.

La forma correcta seria:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: url
    username: username
    password: password
    driver-class-name: driver-class-name
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none

server:
  port: 8088
```

Como se puedes ver tanto la propiedad `server` y `spring` deben de estar en el mismo nivel para que ambas sean raíz.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias opciones para cambiar los puertos, pero básicamente el problema que tienes es en tu archivo de propiedades yaml como lo comenta @Roberto E Moran

otra opción es al ejecutar tu aplicación puedes poner el argumento del puerto:

```sh
java -jar application.jar -server.port=8083
```